# Manipulating text values using Selenium JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium to change the text value of a field. Unfortunately, the field is not an `<input>` but a div with a pseudo class of `::before`

I need to be able to input new text values into this field but have been unable to do so thus far.

The HTML snippet:

```
<div class="stb-LazyChosenDropdown" tabindex="0">
   <div class="icon default" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></div>
   <div class="tiles">
      <div class="input" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter values..." style="width: 383px; height: 17px;"></div>
        ::before
   </div>
```

I can use the following to print the value already in place:

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div.stb-LazyChosenDropdown div.tiles div.input'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')")
 System.out.println(content);
```

Which prints `Enter values...`

But how to change the text value to something new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the element using any locator strategies and Try to add the `textContent`

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent='Steerpike'", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.input[placeholder^='Enter values']")))
```